# How is the 'cut' function setting intervals?

Tags: r, sequence, frequency-distribution

I'm new to R and am trying to set up the components of a frequency table (frequency, cumulative frequency, relative frequency, and cumulative %). I was given a set of 24 numbers (ranging from 64 to 100) to group into categories with a width of 10. Here is where I run into a problem. I want to create 5 categories with 10 numbers in each category (60-69, 70-79, 80-89, 90-99, 100-109). When I sequence from 60 to 109 by 10 in R, it creates categories of 11 (60-70, 70-80, 80-90, etc.). If I ask R to do the same task but from 59-109 by 10, it gives me the correct values for the rest of the code, but my categories are numerically inaccurate. Do I need to use a different function to get the correct result or is there a way for me to set R to count 60-69 as 10 in the same way it does when asking length(60-69): >10  ?

Given 24 points of data, I entered each number into a vector. I turned my vector into a data frame with 1 column that I assigned the vector to. I tried using the sequence command in R to categorize the data frame of 24 numbers into the categories 60-69 thru 100-109 in increments of 10 using the following code:

```
interval_table <- table(cut(data_framex$col1, seq(60, 109, 10)
```

The output gave me :

```
(60,70]  (70,80]  (80,90] (90,100] 
      3        9        8        4
```

When I ask the length of 60:70 in R, it tells me the length=11, so I am assuming it is somehow starting the count at 61 instead of 60 even though the category is inclusive to all numbers between 60 and 70.

If I set the sequence to the following, it gives me the correct counts, but the categories are incorrect.

```
interval_table <- table(cut(data_framex$col1, seq(59, 109, 10)
```

Output:

```
 (59,69]  (69,79]  (79,89]  (89,99] (99,109] 
       2        7       11        3        1
```

See the full code below. Since I am new, I may be thinking about this completely wrong and should be using a different code, but I can't find the answer with my search results. I appreciate the help!

```
x <- c(66, 80, 89, 71, 80, 88, 82, 98, 83, 100, 72, 70, 64, 75, 79, 82, 88, 71, 85, 94, 93, 80, 77, 83)
data_framex <- data.frame(col1 = x)
interval_table <- table(cut(data_framex$col1, seq(60, 109, 10)))
interval_table

Output:
 (60,70]  (70,80]  (80,90] (90,100] 
       3        9        8        4

Desired Output:
 (60,69]  (70,79]  (80,89]  (90,99] (100,109] 
       2        7       11        3        1
```

Comment: Notice the formatting of the intervals: "(60, 70]" indicates the interval is closed on the right and open on the left.  So the integers in the interval are indeed 61 to 70 inclusive.  Also, see the online doc for `cut`, which reads (in part) "`right`
 logical, indicating if the intervals should be closed on the right (and open on the left) or vice versa".

Comment: Note that `cut` assumes continuous vales, you are using discrete counts. You can get closer to what you want with `cut(data_framex$col1, seq(60, 110, 10), right=FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the right parameter in the cut function and set it to FALSE.
This will make the intervals left-closed. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
#for example
# your data
x <- c(66, 80, 89, 71, 80, 88, 82, 98, 83, 100, 72, 70, 64, 75, 79, 82, 88, 71, 85, 94, 93, 80, 77, 83)

# Create a data frame
data_framex <- data.frame(col1 = x)

# Create the intervals with left-closed intervals
interval_table <- table(cut(data_framex$col1, seq(60, 109, 10), right = FALSE))

# Print the result
print(interval_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the desired output names are not correct because it excludes the lower bound and includes the upper bound.  That is (a, b] means a < x <= b so a is never included. See [standard interval notation](https://mathresearch.utsa.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Interval_Notation#Notations_for_intervals) for more information on notation. To fix that use [a,b] as shown below.

```
tab <- table(x %/% 10)
names(tab) <- sprintf("[%s0,%s9]", names(tab), names(tab))
tab

##   [60,69]   [70,79]   [80,89]   [90,99] [100,109] 
##         2         7        11         3         1
```

Alternately just drop the brackets/parentheses

```
names(tab) <- sprintf("%s0-%s9", names(tab), names(tab))
tab

##   60-69   70-79   80-89   90-99 100-109 
##       2       7      11       3       1
```

### Note

```
x <- c(66, 80, 89, 71, 80, 88, 82, 98, 83, 100, 72, 70, 64, 75, 79, 82, 
       88, 71, 85, 94, 93, 80, 77, 83)
```